# Can I remotely debug a linux machine from VS2005?

Tags: linux, debugging, visual-studio-2005

I am developing a cross-platform application in C++ in VS2005. I already know how to run a remote process on a windows box, attach it, and debug from my VS.

Is there a way to do debug a running process on Linux for example? What about other *nix platforms such as Solaris or AIX? I can do emacs+gdb, but if this can be done from VS I'd prefer that.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you try @Matthew's answer and were you able to import the VS2005 Solution into WinGDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2005 and g++ use create completely different debugging symbols. You do realize you'll have to compile the application on linux with g++? (or some other *nix compiler, but not VS2005). So because it's compiled with a different compiler, there's really no way to debug it inside VS2005.

OK, everything I said was essentially true, but it looks like there is a program that will allow you to run gdb inside Visual Studio. Check it out [here.](http://www.wingdb.com/)